# SBCL and Slime do strange things when I try to use Serapeum

Tags: slime, common-lisp

I'm getting *very* strange behaviour when I try to `C-c C-k` the following code into the SLIME REPL running SBCL:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload "serapeum"))

(defpackage #:foo
  (:use #:cl #:serapeum)) ;no symbols to export currently

(in-package #:foo)
```

The operation fails, and SLIME spews the following into my face:

```
    failed AVER: (NULL CURRENT)
This is probably a bug in SBCL itself. (Alternatively, SBCL
might have been corrupted by bad user code, e.g. by an undefined
Lisp operation like (FMAKUNBOUND 'COMPILE), or by stray pointers
from alien code or from unsafe Lisp code; or there might be a
bug in the OS or hardware that SBCL is running on.) If it seems
to be a bug in SBCL itself, the maintainers would like to know
about it. Bug reports are welcome on the SBCL mailing lists,
which you can find at <http://sbcl.sourceforge.net/>.
    [Condition of type SB-INT:BUG]

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-C:COMPILER-ERROR SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD :CONDITION #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR "~@<~?: ~2I~_~A~:>" {1004F4CAD3}> :POSITION 0 :STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/koz/quicklisp/dists/quickl..
  1: (SB-C::READ-FOR-COMPILE-FILE #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/koz/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/split-sequence-1.1/split-sequence.asd" {1004EEABD3}> 0 SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD)
  2: (SB-INT:LOAD-AS-SOURCE #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/koz/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/split-sequence-1.1/split-sequence.asd" {1004EEABD3}> :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :CONTEXT "loading")
  3: ((FLET SB-FASL::LOAD-STREAM :IN LOAD) #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/koz/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/split-sequence-1.1/split-sequence.asd" {1004EEABD3}> NIL)
  4: (LOAD #P"/home/koz/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/split-sequence-1.1/split-sequence.asd" :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :IF-DOES-NOT-EXIST T :EXTERNAL-FORMAT :UTF-8)
  5: (UIOP/UTILITY:CALL-WITH-MUFFLED-CONDITIONS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/LISP-BUILD:LOAD*) {1004EE584B}> ("Overwriting already existing readtable ~S." #(#:FINALIZERS-OFF-WARNING :ASDF-FINALIZERS)))
```

...and so on for ages and ages. I've checked and this does *not* happen if I just load it into SBCL using `sbcl --load` on the file that contains this code. Basically, what the actual hell is going on, and how can I make it not do that?

Comment: https://github.com/slime/slime/issues

Comment: So... this isn't me being crazy, and is actually an issue with SLIME? I don't follow.

Comment: If `slime` fails for such a simple operation, the developers would
want to know. And there's a whole system dedicated for reporting
this. As a developer it's more convenient to get a github notification
than to scour the forums for problems related to your code.